# Circular dependency error when running migrations in Django 1.7c2

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have been reading about django migrations at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/. I also reviewed the commits on the 1.7.x branch in github where I understand that this problem may have been solved. 
Unfortunately I still get the error when running my migrations. The --fake option gives the same error.

I have the following migrations:

'people' app migration:

```
user@host$ /manage.py makemigrations people
Migrations for 'people':
0001_initial.py:
- Create model Person
- Create model Committee
- Create model DepartmentGroup
- Add field department_group to person
- Create model MemberType
- Add field member_type to person
- Alter unique_together for person (1 constraint(s))
- Create model PersonCommittee
- Add field committees to committee
- Add field committee to personcommittee
- Add field member to personcommittee
- Alter unique_together for personcommittee (1 constraint(s))
- Create model Role
- Create proxy model PersonArchive
```

'locations' app migration:

```
user@host$ ./manage.py makemigrations locations
Migrations for 'locations':
0001_initial.py:
- Create model Building
- Create model Institution
- Create model InstitutionAddress
- Add field institution to building
- Add field address to institutionaddress
- Add field institution to institutionaddress
- Create model Room
- Alter unique_together for room (1 constraint(s))
```

Now I run the migrations with

```
./manage.py migrate
```

and this is the error I get

```
django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError: 
[('people', u'0001_initial'), ('locations', u'0001_initial'), 
('people', u'0001_initial')]
```

The full error can be viewed at: http://pastebin.com/jixK6Ve2

My question is if there is still something in the django code that needs to be fixed, see fixed ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22932. If not, is there an option to split the migrations in 2 or more steps to avoid the circular dependency error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The steps indicated by user humitos from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22932#comment:4 seem to have solved the problem.

I basically needed to remove the swappable dependency and the conflicting model and put them in a new empty migration.

Comment: For which app did you need to remove the swappable dependency and conflicting model then put them into a new empty migration? How did you determine which app had the conflicting model?

Comment: The error message you get when you run the migrate command explains in detail the source of the conflicting model.