# django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError in Django 1.7.1

Tags: mysql, django

Just upgraded to Django 1.7.1 and am trying to setup a fresh dev environment. I ran a *users* migration OK, but when I try to run a *tweets* migration, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 106, in handle
    plan = executor.migration_plan(targets)
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 49, in migration_plan
    for migration in self.loader.graph.forwards_plan(target):
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 55, in forwards_plan
    return self.dfs(node, lambda x: self.dependencies.get(x, set()))
  File "/Users/libbyh/Documents/virtualenvs/fyl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 105, in dfs
    raise CircularDependencyError()
django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError
```

So I'm trying to track down the circular dependency. Here are the models ready to migrate:

*users/models.py*

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class UsersTweets(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User')
    tweet = models.ForeignKey('tweets.Tweet')
    source = models.BooleanField() # sent the tweet
    target = models.BooleanField() # received a reply in the tweet

    class Meta:
        managed = True

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=21, unique=True)
    twitter_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    followers = models.IntegerField()
    following = models.IntegerField()
    favorites = models.IntegerField()
    tweets = models.IntegerField()
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    legislator = models.ForeignKey('users.Legislator', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

class Legislator(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    PARTY = (
        ('Democrat','Democrat'),
        ('Republican','Republican'),
        ('Independent','Independent'),
    )
    GENDER = (
        ('M','Man'),
        ('F','Woman'),
    )
    TYPE = (
        ('sen','Senator'),
        ('rep','Representative')
    )
    STATE = (
        ('AK', 'Alaska'),
        ('AL', 'Alabama'),
        ('AR', 'Arkansas'),
        ('AS', 'American Samoa'),
        ('AZ', 'Arizona'),
        ('CA', 'California'),
        ('CO', 'Colorado'),
        ('CT', 'Connecticut'),
        ('DC', 'District of Columbia'),
        ('DE', 'Delaware'),
        ('FL', 'Florida'),
        ('GA', 'Georgia'),
        ('GU', 'Guam'),
        ('HI', 'Hawaii'),
        ('IA', 'Iowa'),
        ('ID', 'Idaho'),
        ('IL', 'Illinois'),
        ('IN', 'Indiana'),
        ('KS', 'Kansas'),
        ('KY', 'Kentucky'),
        ('LA', 'Louisiana'),
        ('MA', 'Massachusetts'),
        ('MD', 'Maryland'),
        ('ME', 'Maine'),
        ('MI', 'Michigan'),
        ('MN', 'Minnesota'),
        ('MO', 'Missouri'),
        ('MP', 'Northern Mariana Islands'),
        ('MS', 'Mississippi'),
        ('MT', 'Montana'),
        ('NA', 'National'),
        ('NC', 'North Carolina'),
        ('ND', 'North Dakota'),
        ('NE', 'Nebraska'),
        ('NH', 'New Hampshire'),
        ('NJ', 'New Jersey'),
        ('NM', 'New Mexico'),
        ('NV', 'Nevada'),
        ('NY', 'New York'),
        ('OH', 'Ohio'),
        ('OK', 'Oklahoma'),
        ('OR', 'Oregon'),
        ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'),
        ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'),
        ('RI', 'Rhode Island'),
        ('SC', 'South Carolina'),
        ('SD', 'South Dakota'),
        ('TN', 'Tennessee'),
        ('TX', 'Texas'),
        ('UT', 'Utah'),
        ('VA', 'Virginia'),
        ('VI', 'Virgin Islands'),
        ('VT', 'Vermont'),
        ('WA', 'Washington'),
        ('WI', 'Wisconsin'),
        ('WV', 'West Virginia'),
        ('WY', 'Wyoming'),
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    chamber = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    party = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    contact_form = models.CharField(max_length=103, blank=True)
    rss_url = models.CharField(max_length=106, blank=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=27, blank=True)
    facebook_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    youtube = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    youtube_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    bioguide_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    thomas_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    opensecrets_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lis_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cspan_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    govtrack_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    votesmart_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ballotpedia_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    washington_post_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    icpsr_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    wikipedia_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    def _get_name_with_honor(self):
        return '%s. %s %s (%s-%s)' % ((self.chamber).title(), self.first_name, self.last_name, self.party[:1], self.state)
    honor_name = property(_get_name_with_honor) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.last_name

    class Meta:
        managed = True
```

*tweets/models.py*

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=21)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    location_geo = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    location_geo_0 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=10, blank=True, null=True)
    location_geo_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=10, blank=True, null=True)
    iso_language = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    user = models.ManyToManyField('users.User', through = "users.UsersTweets")
    class Meta:
        managed = True
```

I checked [another StackOverflow question about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292873/circular-dependency-error-when-running-migrations-in-django-1-7c2), but I don't get any info from my error about where the dependency might be. Tried to follow [this advice](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22932#comment:4) but wasn't sure how to edit the `swappable_dependency`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: still no, sadly. haven't looked at it awhile though.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. In tweets/models.py comment #user = models.ManyToManyField('users.User', through = "users.UsersTweets")
2. makemigrations tweets
3. makemigrations users
4. UNcomment in tweets/models.py user = models.ManyToManyField('users.User', through = "users.UsersTweets")
5. makemigrations tweets
6. migrate
```

Comment: Thanks, @TitanFighter. I'll give it a try.